# SQL Query from Three Related Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I am having trouble putting together a MySQL query.

I have a database with three tables: Location, LocationTypes, and LocationStatus.

I need to retrieve the total of each type of status for each location. So, I the result should look like this:

```
id_LocationType, status, total
1, open, 200
1, closed, 100
2, open, 400
2, closed, 500
```

The query should accessing three tables.

LocationTypes --< Locations --< LocationStatus

I came up with this:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(DISTINCT id_Locations)
    FROM LocationStatus
    GROUP BY status
```

But this does not give me the status by LocationType, It gives me the total status for each type of status, combining all LocationTypes:

```
status, value
open, 600
closed, 600
```

It doesn't distinguish between LocationType (from the LocationType table). Also, it counts all status values. However, as a location can have multiple status records (ie. a record is created each time the status is updated), I want to count only the most recent status update as the valid one.

The schema looks like this:

```
Locations Table
-- id (PK)
-- id_LocationType (FK to LocationTypes Table)
-- name 
-- date_created
-- date_modified

LocationTypes Table
-- id (PK)
-- nameLocationType 
-- date_created
-- date_modified

LocationStatus Table
-- id (PK)
-- id_Location (FK to Location Table)
-- status
-- date_created
-- date_modified
```

So, it is linked like this:

LocationTypes --< Locations --< LocationStatus

How do I put together this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the result by both `LocationType` and `status`. Try this:

```
SELECT id_LocationType, status, COUNT(DISTINCT id_Locations)
FROM Locations join LocationStatus
     ON Locations.id = LocationStatus.id_Location 
GROUP BY id_LocationType, status
```

Comment: Thanks. But the LocationType table is linked to the Locations table. The LocationStatus table is linked to the Locations table. So, I can't get id_LocationType from LocationStatus. I can only get id_Location type from the Locations table.

Comment: Could you post the schema for all the relations? Should be a couple of joins that's all.

Comment: I added the schema in the question above.

Comment: You do not need a join to `LocationType` if it has only one field.

Comment: There are more than one field. I just didn't put them all down. I have now amended the question to show other fields.

Comment: Well, you still don't need the join since you only need the `id_LocationType`  in the result. But you'll need to join it to `LocationType` to get `nameLocationType` for instance.

Comment: So, the final query looks like this:

SELECT id_LocationType, status, COUNT(DISTINCT id_Locations)
FROM Locations join LocationStatus
     ON Locations.id = LocationStatus.id_Location 
GROUP BY id_LocationType, status

?

Comment: It looks like I have it working now. One problem though - this grabs ALL the status updates related to a location. But I want to get only the most recent status update related to a location.

Comment: Add a where clause `where date_created > SOMEDATE` (or `date_modified  > SOMEDATE` depending on how you define _most recent_) to only select the most recent status updates.

Comment: That would only show status between certain dates. What about picking out only the most recent status for a location? If a location has 10 different status updates over a two week period, I only want to count the most recent one.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're asking. If you need to select only the recent status updates, then how does the result look like the one you mention in the post?

Answer (score 0):

**I hope so this query will be helpful for you.**

```
select lt.id as id_LocationType , ls.status,count(*)
    from LocationTypes as lt join Locations as l join LocationStatus as ls
    on lt.id=l.id_LocationType and on l.id=ls.id_location 
    Group by lt.id,ls.status.
```